# Searchbox Javascript - Displaying Alert of Value in Form that Matches one in Database

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop

Sorry, I have been here before, but I cannot seem to get any search value entered into a form to display in an alert. I think it has something to do with the for loop. Everything else looks good to me. Any ideas?

TGIF

```
var fakeDatabase = [];

var foxyShazam = {
    id: 'foxyShazam_FS',
    title: 'Foxy Shazam',
    artist: 'Foxy Shazam',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
    quantity: 50,
    link: "albums/foxyShazam.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Intro: Bombs Away", "Wanna-Be Angel", "Count Me Out", "Bye Bye Symphony", "Unstoppable", "Second Floor", "Oh Lord", "Connect",  "The Only Way to My Heart...", "Killin' It", "Evil Thoughts"]
};

var foxyShazam2 = {
    id: 'foxyShazam_FS_2',
    title: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
    artist: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
    quantity: 50,
    link: "albums/foxyShazam.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Intro: Bombs Away", "Wanna-Be Angel", "Count Me Out", "Bye Bye Symphony", "Unstoppable", "Second Floor", "Oh Lord", "Connect",  "The Only Way to My Heart...", "Killin' It", "Evil Thoughts"]
};

var thriller = {
    id: 'thriller_MJ',
    title: 'Thriller',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady in My Life"]
};

var thriller2 = {
    id: 'thriller_MJ_2',
    title: 'Thriller 2',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson 2',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady in My Life"]
};

var millennium = {
    id: 'millennium_BSB',
    title: 'Millennium',
    artist: 'Backstreet Boys',
    price: '$7.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1999, 4, 18),
    quantity: 15,
    link: "albums/millennium.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Larger Than Life", "I Want It That Way", "Show Me the Meaning", "It's Gotta Be You", "I Need You Tonight", "Don't Want You Back", "Don't Wanna Lose You Now", "The One", "Back to Your Heart", "Spanish Eyes", "No One Else Comes Close", "The Perfect Fan"]
};

var darkSideOfTheMoon = {
    id: 'darkSideOfTheMoon_PinkFloyd',
    title: 'Dark Side of the Moon',
    artist: 'Pink Floyd',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1973, 2, 1),
    quantity: 60,
    link: "albums/darkSideOfTheMoon.html",
    Trackinglist: ["Speak to Me", "Breathe", "On the Run", "Time", "The Great Gig in the Sky", "Money", "Us and Them", "Any Colour You Like", "Brian Damage", "Eclipse"]
};

fakeDatabase.push(foxyShazam, foxyShazam2, thriller, thriller2, millennium, darkSideOfTheMoon);

function search() {
    'use strict';
    var searchVal = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('searchVal', searchVal);
    sessionStorage.getItem('searchVal');
    for (var i=0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
        if (searchVal.value == (fakeDatabase[i].artist) {
        alert(fakeDatabase[i].artist);
        };
    };
    };
};

function init {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById('searchBox').onsubmit = search;
    searchBox.onsubmit = search(fakeDatabase);
        };

window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are several mistakes on the code above

1. Additional '};' in search function
2. init function don't have parentheses in method definition
3. In search function you have used id 'searchBox' as the id for the text box, and in init you have used it as the id for the form
4. I don't see a reason to use sessionStorage

Below is the fixed code

**JavaScript Part**

```
 var fakeDatabase = [];

    var foxyShazam = {
        id: 'foxyShazam_FS',
        title: 'Foxy Shazam',
        artist: 'Foxy Shazam',
        price: '$14.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
        quantity: 50,
        link: "albums/foxyShazam.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Intro: Bombs Away", "Wanna-Be Angel", "Count Me Out", "Bye Bye Symphony", "Unstoppable", "Second Floor", "Oh Lord", "Connect",  "The Only Way to My Heart...", "Killin' It", "Evil Thoughts"]
    };

    var foxyShazam2 = {
        id: 'foxyShazam_FS_2',
        title: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
        artist: 'Foxy Shazam 2',
        price: '$14.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1968, 10, 22),
        quantity: 50,
        link: "albums/foxyShazam.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Intro: Bombs Away", "Wanna-Be Angel", "Count Me Out", "Bye Bye Symphony", "Unstoppable", "Second Floor", "Oh Lord", "Connect",  "The Only Way to My Heart...", "Killin' It", "Evil Thoughts"]
    };

    var thriller = {
        id: 'thriller_MJ',
        title: 'Thriller',
        artist: 'Michael Jackson',
        price: '$12.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
        quantity: 35,
        link: "albums/thriller.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady in My Life"]
    };

    var thriller2 = {
        id: 'thriller_MJ_2',
        title: 'Thriller 2',
        artist: 'Michael Jackson 2',
        price: '$12.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
        quantity: 35,
        link: "albums/thriller.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady in My Life"]
    };

    var millennium = {
        id: 'millennium_BSB',
        title: 'Millennium',
        artist: 'Backstreet Boys',
        price: '$7.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1999, 4, 18),
        quantity: 15,
        link: "albums/millennium.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Larger Than Life", "I Want It That Way", "Show Me the Meaning", "It's Gotta Be You", "I Need You Tonight", "Don't Want You Back", "Don't Wanna Lose You Now", "The One", "Back to Your Heart", "Spanish Eyes", "No One Else Comes Close", "The Perfect Fan"]
    };

    var darkSideOfTheMoon = {
        id: 'darkSideOfTheMoon_PinkFloyd',
        title: 'Dark Side of the Moon',
        artist: 'Pink Floyd',
        price: '$14.99',
        releaseDate: new Date(1973, 2, 1),
        quantity: 60,
        link: "albums/darkSideOfTheMoon.html",
        Trackinglist: ["Speak to Me", "Breathe", "On the Run", "Time", "The Great Gig in the Sky", "Money", "Us and Them", "Any Colour You Like", "Brian Damage", "Eclipse"]
    };

    fakeDatabase.push(foxyShazam, foxyShazam2, thriller, thriller2, millennium, darkSideOfTheMoon);

    function search() {
        'use strict';
        var searchVal = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
        sessionStorage.setItem('searchVal', searchVal);
        sessionStorage.getItem('searchVal');
        for (var i=0; i < fakeDatabase.length; i++) {
            if (searchVal === fakeDatabase[i].artist) {
                alert(fakeDatabase[i].artist);
            };
        };
    };
```

**HTML Part**

```
<form onsubmit="search()">
    <input type="text" id="searchBox">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```